# How can i create a raised center tab button in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'd like to achieve what is described here: http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

Essentially given a tab bar, I'd like the center button to be larger than the others.

Can this be achieved somehow using react-native ? Bonus points if it's a crossplatform solution.